# Basic data summary - determine maximum value by date

Tags: r, summary

This is my first time to use R.  I'm trying to do some basic data summarizing (find max) for plotting.  I can accomplish this in Excel but it takes a while and since I do the same thing over and over, developing an R script makes a lot of sense.  I searched previous posts and found a similar problem, but can't figure out the correct R syntax.  Again, I am an absolute beginner so any help is greatly appreciated.

Problem description:  I have a data frame with two columns: DATE/TIME (10 minute time stamp), and PRESSURE.  I need to determine the maximum value for PRESSURE for each day.

```
     DateAndTime   Pressure
1  8/1/2011 0:06 0.06119370

2  8/1/2011 0:16 0.06003765

3  8/1/2011 0:26 0.06118049
```

I have tried modifying the code below from a previous post (tried deleting the "which.max" portion) but without success.

```
for (imonth in 1:12) {

    month <- which(data[,2]==imonth) 
    monthly_max[imonth] <- max(data[month,3]) 
    maxi[imonth] <- which.max(data[month,3]) 
} 
tabela <- cbind(monthly_max, maxi) 
write.table(tabela, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Comment: Please call `dput` on your dataframe and post the output.

Comment: Do you have a link to the post you got the code from?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a time-series class, like xts or zoo.

```
# create some data that looks like the OP's
NOW <- .POSIXct(1342460400)
d <- data.frame(DateAndTime=format(NOW+seq(0,3600*72,600), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
d$Pressure <- runif(NROW(d))/10

library(xts)  # load the xts package
# create an xts object from the OP's data.frame
x <- xts(d["Pressure"], as.POSIXct(d$DateAndTime))
# apply the max function to each day
dx <- apply.daily(x, max)
#                       Pressure
# 2012-07-16 23:50:00 0.09872622
# 2012-07-17 23:50:00 0.09947256
# 2012-07-18 23:50:00 0.09932375
# 2012-07-19 12:40:00 0.09971159
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#creating some data for demonstration purpose
time1 <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2011-01-08 00:06:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2011-01-18 00:06:00"),by="10 min")
DateAndTime <- format(time1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
Pressure <- rnorm(length(DateAndTime),0.06,0.01)
DF <- data.frame(DateAndTime,Pressure)

#look at first lines
head(DF)

#convert character in datetime format
DF$DateAndTime2 <- strptime(DF$DateAndTime,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="GMT")
DF$Days <- trunc(DF$DateAndTime2,"days")

#create the summary
require(plyr)
summaryDF <- ddply(DF,.(Days),summarise,max(Pressure))
names(summaryDF)<-c("Day","Maximum")

#write to CSV file, which can be read into Excel
write.table(summaryDF,file="output.csv",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,dec=".",sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
dat <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(1,50,2),2), value = rnorm(50))
head(dat)   
require(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(date), summarise, max(value))
```

Comment: This will only work if you've already converted the datetime to just a date, as @Roland does in his answer.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded.  I have a long way to go but this is a very good start.  JW